# Reverse engineering unknown hex/binary representation to decimal

Tags: gps, hexadecimal, decoding, reverse-engineer

I am decoding a device that pumps out location data via network packets.
Lets say we have want to decode altitude. The altitude packet is 4 bytes. So the info in hex is.

```
0x05 0x79 = 5.945313(meters)
```

With testing I determined that the first 2 bytes is everything before the comma. 
Mystery is how hex value "79" gets turned into 945313.

I then crafted my own packets, where I only changed the mentioned 2 bytes and made a table:

```
0x01 = 0.007813
0x02 = 0.015625
0x03 = 0.023438
0x04 = 0.03125
0x05 = 0.039063
0x06 = 0.046875
0x07 = 0.054688
0x08 = 0.0625
0x09 = 0.070313
0x0a = 0.078125
0x0b = 0.085938
0x0c = 0.09375
0x0d = 0.101563
0x0e = 0.109375
0x0f = 0.117188
0x10 = 0.125
0x20 = 0.25
0x30 = 0.376
0x40 = 0.5
0x50 = 0.625
0x60 = 0.75
0x70 = 0.875
0x80 = NaN
```

for example making `0x79 gives = 70 + 09 = 0.875 + 0.070313 = 0.945313` which is correct.

But how to calculate the value without doing this table. There has to be somekind of regularity involved but I cannot see this.
Any ideas?

Comment: Note: `0x05 0x79` looks like two bytes, not four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal part seems to be stored in 1⁄128's, nothing more complex than that.

```
altitude = firstbyte + (secondbyte / 128)
```

Note how everything is increasing linearly in steps of ~0.007813 (and 1/0.007813 ≈ 128), and `0x40` (64) is exactly 0.5, and `0x80` (128) is NaN because 128⁄128 = 1.0 which wouldn't make sense for the decimal part. (Sure, you can technically still decode 0x0580 and get the same result as 0x0600, but I assume it's good practice to only accept data in canonical format.)